# How to enable static code analysis in AOSP development

Tags: android, android-source

I want to integrate some code style checker(formatter) tools or lint to do static code analysis on AOSP during development. I believe this can be done in the building process. I'm curious is there anything I can integrate into the AOSP building process for those checks?

Or does it already exist in the building process? If so, can I configure the check rules?

Any docs/ wikis or instructions are appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but I believe this might be what you are looking for: https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle

Comment: @JustSightseeing ktlint-gradle works well in application projects since the build system is Gradle. However, I want to apply something like ktlint on the AOSP project, which is not built by Gradle.

Comment: Just making sure you are aware of: https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/tradefed/development/error-prone

Comment: @MorrisonChang That's super helpful, and I found that AOSP will parse `LOCAL_ERROR_PRONE_FLAGS` flag if RUN_ERROR_PRONE is set to true, but LOCAL_ERROR_PRONE_FLAGS is not working for me even I've declared it in module's Android.mk. What am I missing here?